# How do I set focus back to textbox in subform in 'LostFocus event procedure

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How do I set focus back to textbox in subform in `LostFocus` event procedure.

I have used `Me.textxboxName.setFocus` and focus moves to the next control in the subform.
I have also tried `Cancel = True` but that only works in the Exit event procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon you have chosen the wrong event. This code will mean that you can never leave the control once you enter:

```
Private Sub AText_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

[Consider the order of events](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HP005186761.aspx)

```
Exit (control) → LostFocus (control) 
      → Unload (form) → Deactivate (form) → Close (form)
```